# Why does "java -version" print its output to error stream?

Tags: java

Let us try to redirect standard error for `java`:

```
java -version 2> ~/error.txt
```

`error.txt` is populated with version.

Let us try to redirect standard output:

```
java -version > ~/output.txt
```

`output.txt` is empty.

Why does `java` binary print normal output to error stream?

Comment: Most compilers do that.

Comment: @EJP That is not an answer. My follow up questions would be - why? 
JeffBowman has a good explanation.

Comment: You are correct. It's not an answer. That's why I posted it as a comment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does 'java -version' go to stderr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13483443/why-does-java-version-go-to-stderr)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to [the Java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html#BABDJJFI):

> -showversion
>
> Displays version information and continues execution of the application. This option is equivalent to the `-version` option except that the latter instructs the JVM to exit after displaying version information.
>
> -version
>
> Displays version information and then exits. This option is equivalent to the `-showversion` option except that the latter does not instruct the JVM to exit after displaying version information.

Now consider [Wikipedia's definition of stderr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams):

> Standard error is another output stream typically used by programs to output error messages or diagnostics.

Most POSIX-centric tools prescribe a very careful specification for their stdout stream, so the tool's output can be piped elsewhere. Stderr is much less prescribed, and used liberally for logging and errors.

With `-showversion`, Java allows the version information to be printed adjacent to a running application. However, if the version information were printed to `stdout`, it would be indistinguishable from the normal application output that *could* accompany it, forcing you to scan for and remove that line of output yourself. Of course, with `-version` instead of `-showversion`, the version string very likely *is* the intended output, but keeping consistency is a decent end in itself.

For what it's worth, [printing requested metadata to stderr vs stdout is something of an open question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2199624/1426891), so there's little in terms of "standard practice" aside from behavior documented per-application.

To work around this, just redirect stderr to stdout:

```
VERSION=$(java -version 2>&1)
```

Comment: On OpenJdk 11.0.1 there is 4 options: `-version`, `--version`, `-showversion` and `--showversion`. Both `version`and `showversion`does the same effect, but with only one dash it output as error, with two dash both output as normal and can be stored into variables. If you want to get, for some reason, error output and store it into variable you can do like this: 
> Invoke-Expression "java -version" -ErrorVariable javaVaraible
java : openjdk version "11.0.1" 2018-10-16
...
> $javaVaraible
java : openjdk version "11.0.1" 2018-10-16
...

Answer (score 2):

Seems like its a bug or just an inconsistency the java command has compared to many other commands in UNIX send version output to stdout:

`mvn -v > ~/output.txt # works as expected`

[There is a bug](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4380614) for it but this was closed.  Probably Oracle can't fix the problem since it might cause for problems for systems that expect it to behave this way.