# Bash script to read output of 'openssl help'

Tags: string, bash, openssl

I try to read the output of the bash command 'openssl help' and put it in a string variable for further processing.

To be precise I want to test all Cipher commands.

First I tried to read the output of the command 'openssl ciphers'. But I got only ciphers and not the cipher commands. But if I type 'openssl help' then the cipher commands are shown. The problem is that now the output of the command is not saved in my variable.

```
CIPHER=`openssl ciphers`
echo "Output:"
echo $CIPHER
```

This works. But unfortunately the content of $CIPHER is not what I need.

```
CIPHER=`openssl help`
echo "Output:"
echo $CIPHER
```

This doesnt work. The variable CIPHER is empty. Why??

Comment: Do you want `openssl ciphers` or `openssl help`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does seem `openssl help` contents are written to the standard error stream `stderr(2)` instead of `stdout(1)`. Suggest re-redirecting the error stream (represented by file descriptor 2) to standard output(represented by file descriptor 1) to fix the issue.

Since the output contains a multi-line stream, recommend enclosing the `$(..)` command-substitution over backticks (outdated technique) with proper double-quotes.

```
sslOutput="$(openssl help 2>&1)"
printf "%s\n" "${sslOutput}"
```

See why [`$(..)` is prefereed over legacy `..` syntax for command substitution.](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2006)

Comment: Also see [Should the command line “usage” be printed on stdout or stderr?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2199624/608639)